# Add element to this.$el before rendering

Tags: marionette

I have the following template:

```
<a data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui btn-right" data-theme="e"></a> <p id="msg"></p>
```

which is loaded from the following view:

```
define(['backbone', 'marionette', 'jquery', 'jquerymobile', 'hbs!templates/Popup'],
function (Backbone, Marionette, $, jqm, template) {
    return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        attributes: function() {
            return {
                // For dialogs to work correctly, url will need to be unique
                'id' : 'popupMsg',
                'data-role': 'popup',
                'class': 'ui-content'
            };
        },
        template: template,
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this);
        },
        onBeforeRender: function(){
            this.$el.find("#msg").text("{{$ message}}");
        }
    });
});
```

I try to add some text in the **#msg** element of the template by adding the code above in **OnBeforeRender** event. The reason is that I want to pass a string to be localized from handlebars before the view is rendered.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: `onBeforeAttach: function() { return this.$el.find('#override_settings').addClass('1111');
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `#msg` element won't exist until the view is rendered, so trying to set its text in `onBeforeRender` won't work.

Why can't you make the handlebars expression just a part of the template?